# Ignoring the presence of an ActiveRecord attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a graceful way to tell Rails to pretend an attribute isn't present for a particular block of code?  I'm doing some meta programming on an ActiveRecord model and it may or may not have specific attributes defined.  I'm trying to figure out how to test the situations where attributes aren't defined.

Comment: Maybe? It would be really helpful if you could show some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#has_attribute?`

Returns `true` if the given attribute is in the attributes hash, otherwise `false` and can me called as class or instance method. e.g

```
MyModel.has_attribute? :attribute_name
MyModel.first.has_attribute? :attribute_name
```

See [API docs reference for `has_attribute?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/has_attribute%3F)

#### Even better:

You can use plain old ruby `method_defined?`

See [API docs reference for `method_defined?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/method_defined%3F)